# Remove the previous ajax called result?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery and I have 2 ajax call function. When I call the first ajax request then
the result will display at div id="result". Then I call the second ajax and I want it to display at div id="result" as well and replace the previous result which return from first ajax. From my tested, I still able to see the previous result under browser developer tools.

The second question is, if repeatly click will cause memory leak or not?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax/func1",
  type: "post"
});

$.ajax({
  url: "ajax/func2",
  type: "post"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Then I call the second ajax and I want it to display at div id="result" as well and replace the previous result which return from first ajax.

Using the `html()` method should replace the content with the returned result every time.
You can assign the result to your div in the `done` callback for example.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax/func1",
  type: "post"
}).done(function(result) { 
  $("#result").html(result);
});

$.ajax({
  url: "ajax/func2",
  type: "post"
}).done(function(result) { 
  $("#result").html(result);
});
```

`done` is essentially the same as `success` but if I understood the comments in the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) correctly is might be deprecated soon.

> **Deprecation Notice**: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
> jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To
> prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(),
> jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

#### if repeatedly click will cause memory leak or not?

No, it should not cause a memory leak. All requests should execute after each other.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is essentially single-threaded, so your calls will never conflict or cause memory leaks. However, the timing is undetermined. The first call that completes will be executed first.

In other words, all asynchronous callbacks will happen on the same thread, sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

If there are two ajax async request, second request can be completed before your first request. In this case you will see first result in the end. 
You should call second ajax request in success callback of your first request. For example:

```
 $.ajax({
  url:'someurl',
  type:'post'
  success: function(){
  // Insert smth in result div
  // call second ajax request
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .html(' ') - html function with null string before the second result which will replace the first result as empty and then the result of the second ajax call will be replaced.

The following is the code:

$.ajax({

url:'someurl',

type:'post'

success: function(){

$("#result").html(result);

}

});

$.ajax({

url: "ajax/func2",

type: "post"

success: function(){

$("#result").html(' ');

$("#result").html(result);

}

});